# Download a Word doc via PHP creates a different file than download it directly from the URL

Tags: php

There is a Word doc with a known URL. If I point my browser at it, it downloads to my computer. If I try to download it via PHP, it downloads, but with differences. In this case, it mixes up right foot and left foot (RF and LF) all over the place. What is wrong with my PHP code that it downloads a version of the Word Doc different than what my browser gets?

```
$wordurl = 'https://www.copperknob.co.uk/downloadsheet.aspx?StepsheetID=142209';
$saveFileName = 'sample.doc';
file_put_contents($saveFileName, file_get_contents( $wordurl ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the file server has some validations, User-Agent e.g.